# Detect if any right-to-left language is installed

Tags: .net, unicode, globalization

What is the easiest way to detect whether any right-to-left language is installed on the host Windows OS?

(I need this in order to know if LTR marks will be displayed as squares, or work properly on the host OS)

Comment: Oh no, someone just deleted the answer. It actually contained useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably unmanaged API like [IsValidLanguageGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318677.aspx), [IsValidLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318681.aspx) (or [IsValidLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318679.aspx)) or [IsValidCodePage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318674.aspx) is what you are looking for

For example the code

```
if (IsValidLanguageGroup (LGRPID_ARABIC, LGRPID_INSTALLED) ||
    IsValidLanguageGroup (LGRPID_TURKIC, LGRPID_INSTALLED) || 
    IsValidLanguageGroup (LGRPID_HEBREW, LGRPID_INSTALLED)) {
    // RTL is supported 
}
```

can be used to test whether you have at least one from two most known right-to-left (RTL) languages installed on the windows computer. I don't know the corresponding .NET API, but probably [CultureInfo.GetCultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx) could be used in your case.

**UPDATED**: I included Thai language group in the list of language groups for testing, but I am not sure, that any of this languages you really need. Typically you application supports only selected languages.

Comment: Thai script is left-to-right. I believe the language groups to check for are LGRPID_ARABIC, LGRPID_HEBREW & LGRPID_TURKIC.